# SQL query clarificaiton

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
select count(distinct customerId) count
    from `test_table1` 
   and customerId not in (select distinct customer_id from `test_table2` )
```

```
select count(distinct customerId) count
    from `test_table1` 
   and customerId not in (select distinct customer_id from `test_table2` where customer_id is not null)
```

First query returns zero records which is not right.
Second query returns the right number of records.
Difference is adding the not null condition in the second query.
Why is the first query corrupted?. Can someone explain me what is happening internally?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ? the `and customerId` should be `where customerId` !

Answer (score 0):

I guess `test_table1`.`customerId` is all null, so in the first query you have no results because the subquery include a null custemer_id.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem:

The `NOT IN`operator in SQL compares values on an equality basis.
When a `customer_id` in `test_table1` is `NULL`, it cannot be equal to any `customer_id` in `test_table2`, even if `customer_id` is also `NULL` in `test_table2`.
This results in all `customer_ids` from `test_table1` being excluded, leading to a zero count.

> Solution:

The additional `WHERE customer_id IS NOT NULL` condition in the subquery effectively removes potential matches from `test_table2 where customer_id is NULL`.
This allows the `NOT IN` operator to work correctly for non-NULL customer_id values in both tables.
Only **customer_ids** from test_table1 that genuinely do not exist in test_table2 (either with a non-NULL value or missing altogether) are excluded, providing the desired count.

Regards